# Is this picture of the covariant derivative correct

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am reading O'Neil's Elementary Differential Geometry on my own. On page 81 he gave the following definition:

Let $W$ be a vector field of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $v$ be a tangent vector field to $\mathbb{R}^3$ at the point $p$. The *covariant derivative of $W$ with respect to $v$ is the tangent vector*
$$ \nabla_v W = W(p+tv)'(0) $$
at the point $p$.

So, I tried to draw a picture and produced the following, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

[image]

Can somebody comment on this? And if it's incorrect, what should the correct picture be?

Comment: Upon further review, I get your picture, maybe choose a simpler $W(p+tv)$ curve to see it and focus on say $t=0$ and $t = \triangle t$ for quasi-small $t$. You should be able to see the covariant derivative as a new vector which describes how $W$ is changing in the $v$-direction at $p$. Perhaps, http://www.supermath.info/DifferentialGeometry2015.pdf will be helpful, I started, but they're incomplete, some notes to parallel Oneiil

Answer (score 0):

The derivative $W(p+tv)'(0)$ can be written $\frac{W(p+\triangle t)-W(p)}{\triangle t}$ with $\triangle t \rightarrow 0$ in other words, 
$$ W(p+\triangle t)-W(p) \approx  W(p+tv)'(0) \triangle t$$
for small $\triangle t$ which is to say that $\nabla_v W = W(p+tv)'(0)$ points in the direction $W(p+\triangle t)-W(p)$ at $p$ (approximately for small $\triangle t)$. I have attempted to illustrate this with the red vector in the picture below:

[image: Covariant Derivative]

In summary, I think your picture is just about the right thing to visualize, but, I think it helps to be explicit about where the covariant derivative fits into the picture. It might be useful to imagine this picture not just for one $v$ but for all possible $v$ at $p$ then we'd generate some sort of surface over the plane at $p$ and I believe the covariant derivative would lie tangent to the tangent plane of that surface.

Comment: I just started watching your video lectures and they are very helpful in helping me self-study for differential geometry. Thank you for posting them.